# Django: Ignore spaces for specific query in queryset

Tags: python, django

Input: OFG 5T4 WR4 2-3
Does not give any results for ofg5t4wr42-3.

However, that's how `ticket_reference` is saved in my database, while I show it on tickets as seen in the input, to make it easier to read. Can I replace `ticket_reference__icontains` with any other "filter" to "ignore" spaces for ticket_reference queries.

```
def queryset(self, queryset):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    # Search
    search = cleaned_data.get('search')
    if search:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(company_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(first_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(email__icontains=search) |
            Q(ticket_reference__icontains=search)
        )
```

Comment: Could you not just manipulate the input? Filtering the database seems a bit "hard way round"

Comment: What holds me back is that 'searchers' could also type in First_Name Last_Name (E.g. John Doe) If I remove spaces for any input, then last_name__icontains etc. won't give any results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the whitespace like this:

```
def queryset(self, queryset):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    # Search
    search = cleaned_data.get('search')
    if search:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(company_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(first_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=search) |
            Q(email__icontains=search) |
            Q(ticket_reference__icontains=search.replace(" ", "")
        )
```

Note that this is still rather limited, e.g. searching for "John Doe" will *not* find an entry with first_name="John", last_name="Doe" (because neither first_name nor last_name contain "John Doe").

If you are using PostgreSQL, I would suggest looking into the Django documentation on [Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I will look into Full text search as well.